# Disable/hide refresh button in Firefox browser

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I want to disable the RightClick>Reload functionality in Firefox.

I know that it cannot be done through js running on a specific web page.

1. How to disable it entirely for the browser? (Assuming I can alter the browser behavior)
2. Is it possible to create a manual patch/addon that makes this change in the Firefox code base?

Answer (score 0):

The browser window contains three [`<command>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/command) related to reloading pages: `Browser:Reload`, `Browser:ReloadOrDuplicate`, `Browser:ReloadSkipCache` (I didn't bother figuring out how these are triggered). The first one is the only important one because the other two will disable automatically if it is disabled (they contain the corresponding [`<observes>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/observes)). So your extension would need to run the following code in the browser window:

```
document.getElementById("Browser:Reload").setAttribute("disabled", "true");
```

Only problem is that the browser window itself will also disable/enable this command, from the `onLocationChange()` method of its [progress listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners) (the command should be disabled for `about:blank`). I guess that the solution is to register your own progress listener do the same thing in the `onLocationChange()` method (your listener should be called after the browser's because it is registered later).

Answer (score 0):

If you do it via a XUL overlay, you can completely disable it:

<command id="Browser:Reload" oncommand=""/>

<command id="Browser:ReloadOrDuplicate" oncommand=""/>

<command id="Browser:ReloadSkipCache" oncommand=""/>

Then you don't need to add a listener.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to reinvent the wheel. Use [Menu Editor](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/menu-editor/). I've been using it for ages. Should be enough.

Install it, open settings, choose `Main context menu` from dropdown. Find `Reload` and uncheck it. Voila.